# Copied django project to shared host from repo - can't find settings

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

I setup Django successfully on my shared Bluehost account following the tutorial below:
http://www.nyayapati.com/srao/2012/08/setup-python-2-7-and-django-1-4-on-bluehost/

I am now having problems with a Django project I have copied from a GitHub repo to my Bluehost directory. I am getting this error when I run python mysite.fcgi in my virtualenv

```
go-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
```

Any thoughts on where to look for errors? I have checked .htaccess and the mysite.fcgi file in my www directory, the pointer to settings in my manage.py and these seem as they should be. Running python manage.py runserver on the project says there are no errors.

Lee

Comment: What type of server? My experience with this error using Apache's virtual host is that apache virtual host points to the root directory of the project where it can find the wsgi file.  that wsgi file has a reference to the settings file.  So it's most likely the path for your virtual host is not pointing to the right location where your wsgi file can be found.  Either that or the wsgi file is pointing to the wrong location where your settings.py file can be found.  Most likely it's the first issue.

Comment: This is a shared host so I am using fcgi to redirect and execute the project and I installed python as in the linked tutorial.I know my django setup works becuase I got the Django tutorial projectrunning.  I checked the wsgi file and it seems to be referencing the right place. os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings"). Also I can get see the dev environment producing a proper page with curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to sacrac on the django listserve I got the answer - I needed to make my mysite.fcgi file in my www directory look like this:

```
#!/home5/myorg/.virtualenvs/mydjango/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/<user_name>/projects/")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/<user_name>/projects/yourproyect")

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<project_name>.settings'
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
WSGIServer(WSGIHandler()).run()
```

Not sure why this works, but it did.